# NoReverseMatch at /Reverse for 'newsdesc' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found

Tags: python, django, rest

``I am running a django project to display a website. Here is my `views.py`:

```
def news_desc(request,slug):
# request.session.flush()
news=NewsPort.objects.get(news_title_slug=str(slug))
return render(request,'accounts/newsdesc.html',{'news':news, 'slug':slug})
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
path('login/', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
path('logout/', views.user_logout, name='user_logout'),
# path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('<int:pk>/',views.index_with_pk, name='index_with_pk'),
path('profile/<int:pk>/',views.profile_detail,name='profile_detail'),
path('profile/<int:pk>/edit/',views.profile_edit,name='profile_edit'),
path('profile/<int:pk>/wallet/',views.wallet_view,name='wallet_view'),
path('profile/<int:pk>/wallet/transac',views.history_transac,name='history_transac'),
path('news/all/', views.news_all, name='news_all'),
path('profile/<int:pk>/maps/',views.map_view,name='map_view'),
path('news/<slug:slug>/',views.news_desc,name='newsdesc'),
```

]

When I run, I'm getting an error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'newsdesc' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/news/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

The error is during template rendering.I cant able to login ,signup and logout.

Here is my main urls.py :

```
    router=routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register('profiles',views.ProfileView)
router.register('requests',views.RequestsView)
router.register('transactions',views.TransactionView)
router.register('login',views.LoginView)
router.register('wallets',views.WalletView)
router.register('purchasedtickets',views.PurchasedTicketView)
router.register('grocerycontents',views.PurchasedContentView)
router.register('merchants',views.MerchantView)
router.register('merchantitems',views.MerchantItemView)
router.register('groceries',views.GroceryView)
router.register('commodityitems',views.CommodityItemView)
router.register('transview',views.TransactionsView,base_name='Transactions_view')
router.register('tokenidview',views.TokenIDView,base_name='Token_view')
router.register('barcodetransfer',views.BarCodeView)
router.register('apptransfer',views.AppTransferView)


admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/',include(router.urls)),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('accounts/',include('accounts.urls'),name='accounts'),
    path('merchants/',include('merchants.urls'),name='merchants'),
    path('groceries/', include('groceries.urls'), name='groceries'),
    path('home/rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it is a string @LinhNguyen

Comment: The error is coming from the template where you have an empty `slug`. Post the relevant portion that contains the `{% url 'newsdesc' ...` tag.

Comment: yes please post the url that you put in your template

Comment: {% if news.newspic %}
                  <img src="{{ news.newspic.url }}" style="height:300px;width:600px;" class='img-fluid profimg' alt="Cannot be found!">
                {% endif %}

Comment: you declared the url name already you can just use `{% url 'newsdesc' some string %}`

Comment: Now i am getting an error like this "Reverse for 'news_desc' not found." Is there anything i need to add ?I tried adding HttpResponseRedirect in views.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the template that's used by `views.index`. It's likely how you're iterating over the `NewsPort` collection and generating the link to `newsdesc`. Or you have data that has an empty string for the slug. In which case you're either not setting it or it's a testing artifact.

Answer (score 0):

A normal detail view will be as follows

```
def news_desc(request,slug):
   news = get_object_or_404(NewsPort, slug=slug)
   return render(request,'accounts/newsdesc.html',{'news':news})
```

Then you can give link of this detail view url in your list view as follows

```
<a href="{% url 'newsdesc' slug=slug %} ">Detail View</a>
```

Comment: Now i am getting an error like this "Reverse for 'news_desc' not found." Is there anything i need to add ?I tried adding HttpResponseRedirect in views.

Comment: The url you have mentioned is in your main url or in app url?

Comment: The mentioned is App url

Comment: can you post both url files here

Comment: remove the name attribute of this particular app from the main url and check

Comment: if i am manually entering "127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/ , it is working. But automatically its not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203583/discussion-between-karthik-j-and-user6837382).